# Xdotool Fails On Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, keystroke, simulate, xdotool

I'm running retropie on my Raspberry Pi, and I want to figure out a way to use the GPIO to simulate keystrokes. Xdotool seems like my best bet, but it doesn't work locally or over ssh. When I enter `xdotool key 'd'` I get the error: 
`Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance`

Every answer so far claims that to solve this issue I have to do some variation of `export DISPLAY=":0" xdotool key 'd'` but this doesn't do anything, it just goes to the next line. I'm pretty new to linux, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for your frustration with getting this to work, but tThis Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related sites http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux) OR even http://superuser.com . Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled across an answer that worked for me.  Simply running "xauth" as Pi at the command line told me which file was being used by xauthority (/home/pi/.Xauthority in this case.)

Hope this helps

```
export XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority; export DISPLAY=:0; xdotool key Return
```